# Host machine not able to ping the server until a ping is initiated from the server

Tags: networking, local-area-network

We are facing an issue in the network.

We are not able to ping the server from the host machine until we initiate a ping from server to the host.

We are having 1 L3 Switch {(C3560E-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 12.2(55)SE5, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)} which is directly connected to 2 L2 switch{(C2960-LANLITEK9-M), Version 12.2(55)SE7, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)}

L3 Switch is connected with 9 Redhat servers and 6 L2 Switches.

In L3 switch we have Vlan100 Server(192.168.1.1) , Vlan110 Client(172.168.1.1), and Ip routing is enabled

Issue:

When i try to ping from host to server its not pinging until we first initiate a ping from the server to client. Once a ping is initiated from the server to host the connectivity between server and host is up.

We have to keep the ping on all the time from the host machine to have the connectivity up and running. If we stop the ping the connectivity stops and again we have to initiate a ping from server to get the connectivity up.

I checked all the arp entries they are find but am not able to find the exact problem.

Kindly help me out to resolve it.

I have attached running config of L3 and L2 switch.

---

---

  -

---

##

Comment: Please use the following link to see the running configuration of the switches.
"https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2uek8FhVGQOfjJXUDk3eU96NktGQ2Q0cXhHVDlKOGhnc3QxdVdoUXhpYURZb0lpM29nek0&usp=sharing"

Comment: Is the l3 switch the default gateway for each subnet or are there static routes added to each machine for the other subnet

Comment: L3 is the default gateway for each subnet. Vlan110 ip  172.16.1.1

Comment: On the L2 switch, the ports are in access mode but they don't have a vlan associated to them. I would expect it to be the same as the L3 switch, with the vlan defined.

Comment: we have default vlan 1 on l2 switch. all the port are in vlan 1

Comment: Yes but nothing on the l3 switch is on vlan1. Add vlan100 to the l2 switch and set the port to that and things should start working both ways

Comment: I have created vlan 100 for server and vlan 110 for the clients.

Comment: on the clients we have default gateway as172.16.1.1so request directly goes to the l3 switch.

Comment: the above problem happens when we don't have any activity on the servers from the clients. if some activity is happening all the time the connectivity is up. even if there is no activity for half an hour we have to initiate the ping from the server to get it back it on. even though we have mac entry on the switch all the time.